# ¿Cómo uso un Scanner desde un fichero de texto?

Tags: java, archivo, java-util-scanner, filereader

estoy tratando de leer un fichero de texto y buscar una palabra dentro de él. El código es el siguiente:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *  El fichero se presupone que está en el directorio de trabajo y se llama Pruebas.txt
 */ 
public class Filtra {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);   //Creamos el Scanner que lee el teclado
        System.out.println("Fichero de texto: ");   //Introduccion del nombre del fichero
        String filePath = teclado.next();
        System.out.println("Palabra a buscar: "); //Introduccion de la palabra a buscar
        String word = teclado.next();
        System.out.println("Buscando las apariciones de la palabra"  
                               + " en el fichero: " + filePath);
        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(filePath));    //Creamos el Scanner a partir del File. En este momento se comprueba que existe el mismo
            int numLine = 0;
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {   //Mientras haya tokens en el archivo
                String line = s.nextLine();
                numLine++;
                if (line.contains(word)) {
                    System.out.println(numLine + ": " + line);
                }
            }
            s.close();
            System.out.println("Fin del proceso.");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("El fichero " + filePath + " no existe.");
        }
        teclado.close();                  
    }
} // de main
```

El objetivo es que uno introduzca por teclado el nombre de un fichero (filePath) y una palabra a buscar (word), entonces mediante el while se lee todo el fichero. En caso de no encontrar el fichero salta la excepción FileNotFoundException y finaliza el programa. Pues bien, cuando introduzco el nombre del fichero (Pruebas.txt) y busco una palabra, me salta el mensaje de "El fichero Pruebas.txt no existe."
El contenido del fichero es el siguiente:

> Uso de Scanner.
> Uso de PrintWriter.
>
> Ejemplo de un fichero
>
> con 10 líneas y
>
> 16 palabras.

Pd: el fichero se encuentra en el mismo directorio que el proyecto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si se le pasa sólo el nombre del archivo Java busca en el directorio donde se encuentra el proyecto, no en los paquetes de este. Como mi archivo estaba en un paquete saltaba la excepción `NotFileFound`.

Answer (score 3):

Te salta el mensaje de "El fichero Pruebas.txt no existe." porque lo que de verdad te está pidiendo es la dirección del archivo. Consigue la ruta desde propiedades del archivo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas, gracias por contestar. Aunque lo haga de esta forma me dice que el archivo no existe. Además, pensaba que cuando no le indicabas la ruta y solo introducías el nombre, java buscaba dentro del directorio del proyecto.

Answer (score 3):

Para leer un fichero necesitas utilizar el objeto filereader y bufferedreader, te dejo un ejemplo a continuación:

```
public static void leerFichero() throws IOException { // metodo leerFichero capturando la IOException

    File f = null; // Se inicializa todo a nulo

    FileReader fr = null;

    BufferedReader br = null;

    try { // inicio del try

        f = new File("fichero.txt"); // ruta del fichero

        fr = new FileReader(f); // Se crea un FileReader y un BufferedReader

        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String linea;

        while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) { // Si la linea no es nula, se lee

            if (linea != null) {// Aqui si la linea no es nula, se mete en la cadena para guardarla

                palabra = linea;

            }

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { // catch para la capturar la excepcion FileNotFoundException e

        e.printStackTrace(); // mensaje para la captura de la excepcion

    }

}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: En teoría también puedo leer un fichero con la clase Scanner, ya que con un while (usando scanner.hasNextLine() como guarda) obtengo cada una de las líneas. De todas formas, esto es un ejercicio de clase y la solución hace lo mismo. El único problema que tengo es que cuando le paso la dirección del fichero, simplemente me salta la excepción.